# Unwrapped UV window not displaying

Tags: texturing

I marked the seams on my object.  Then, I selected one face and hit "A" to select all faces.  I right clicked on my object and selected UV Unwrap Faces/Unwrap for a custom unwrap. But, the unwrapped UV window is not there; just the one window of my object is showing.  The window of the unwrapped faces didn't pop up on the left in a new window.  Where is it? How do I access that missing window if it doesn't come up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The window of the unwrapped faces didn't pop up on the left in a new window.

The UV Editor doesn't automatically pop up, you need to open the UV Editor manually by creating a new panel and selecting it:

[image: UV Editor]

Comment: Thank you!  I forgot that little drop down was there!  Very helpful.

Comment: No problem, good luck with your project!